# Adding to Word Template from Access Using VBA not working - where did I go wrong?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm currently working on an "auto labeler" program - the program is supposed to take the the details of a job entered on an Access form, and then using an already created Word template, correctly pass in the information from the Access table into the template. That it can do no problem.

The issue is when I'm trying to get the code to correctly format the labels. Each label page has 12 labels (3 columns, 4 rows) available to print on, however it is not necessary to use all 12. And sometime we reuse old label sheets that have missing labels. Previously, my program would just pass the information through and it would appear on the top left label within the template. However, I would like the program to take in user input via Access's toggle buttons, and pass the information into the correct label cell on a new Word doc using my label template, as well as delete extra label cells that are not necessary for the order.

Code:

```
Private Sub LabelMake_Click()
    'Required: Tools > Refences: Add reference to Microsoft Word Object Library
    
    'Initializes variables need for labels to appear in correct spot on template
    Dim labelRemainder As Integer
    Dim numberOfFullPages As Integer
    Dim numberOfLabels As Integer
    Dim startLabelID As Long
    Dim labelsPerPage As Integer
    Dim strWordDoc  As String

    
    'For L.D.T tests, this should be stagnant. allows program to calculate amount of labels needed.
    labelsPerPage = 12
    numberOfLabels = [Forms]![LDT test Label Maker]![Qty]
    numberOfFullPages = numberOfLabels \ labelsPerPage
    labelRemainder = numberOfLabels Mod 12
    startLabelID = [Forms]![LDT test Label Maker]![ID]
    

    
    'Path to the word document of the Mail Merge
    '###-1 CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE TO POINT TO YOUR DOCUMENT!!
    strWordDoc = [My template path]

    ' Call the code to merge the latest info
    Call startMerge(strWordDoc, startLabelID, numberOfLabels, numberOfFullPages, labelsPerPage, labelRemainder)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "LDT Squares"
End Sub


Function startMerge(strWordDoc As String, startLabelID As Long, numberOfLabels As Integer, numberOfFullPages As Integer, labelsPerPage As Integer, numberRemainingLabels As Integer)
    Dim oWord           As Object
    Dim oWdoc           As Word.Document
    Dim wdInputName     As String
    Dim wdOutputName    As String
    Dim outFileName     As String
    Dim selectedLabelsBool(30) As Boolean
    Dim toggleNames(30) As String
    Dim oSel As Word.Selection
    Dim strTemplate As String
    
    'Creates step function in order to loop through labels
    Dim numberOfFullPagesForStep As Integer
    If numberOfFullPages = 0 Then
            numberOfFullPagesForStep = 1
        Else
            numberOfFullPagesForStep = numberOfFullPages
    End If
    
    'Check for the correct number of toggle buttons clicked
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strF As String
    strF = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
    i = 0 'initialize
    For Each ctl In Forms(strF).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Text19" Then
            selectedLabelsBool(i) = ctl.Value
            toggleNames(i) = ctl.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ctl
    
    'Set temporary txt file location
    Dim tempPath As String
    tempPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\"

    'Loop until all labels have been printed
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 1 To numberOfFullPages + 1 Step numberOfFullPagesForStep
    
        'Create a temporary QueryDef to hold the query
        Dim sql As String
        If a = 1 Then
                If numberOfFullPages = 0 Then
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM [LDT test Label] WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & startLabelID - 1 & " AND " & startLabelID + numberOfLabels - 1
                    Else
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM [LDT test Label] WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & startLabelID & " AND " & startLabelID + (numberOfFullPages * labelsPerPage) - 1
                End If
            Else
                sql = "SELECT * FROM [LDT test Label] WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & startLabelID + (numberOfFullPages * labelsPerPage) - 1 & " AND " & startLabelID + numberOfLabels
        End If
        
        Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
        Dim qdName As String
        Set qd = New DAO.QueryDef
        qd.sql = sql
        qdName = "labelsForMerge" & Format(Now(), "ddmmmmyyyyhhmmss")
        qd.Name = qdName
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append qd
    
        'Export the data using TransferText
        Dim tempFile As String
        tempFile = tempPath & Format(Now(), "ddmmmmyyyyhhmmss") & "tempLabelDataForMerge.txt"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , qdName, tempFile, True
        
        'Clean up
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdName
        qd.Close
        Set qd = Nothing
    
        'Check if word is open
        Dim docWord As Object
        On Error Resume Next
            Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Word isn't running so start it
                Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        'Open the template
        Let strTemplate = strWordDoc
        Set docWord = oWord.Documents.Add(Template:=strWordDoc, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
        
        'Delete labels that the user did not select as available
        If a = numberOfFullPages + 1 Then
                Dim R As Integer 'row placeholder
                Dim c As Integer 'column placeholder
                Dim j As Integer
                j = 0 'initialize
                Dim availableLabelPosition As Integer
                
                Select Case labelsPerPage
                    Case 12
                        For j = 0 To labelsPerPage - 1
                            If selectedLabelsBool(j) = False Then
                                availableLabelPosition = GetNumeric(toggleNames(j))
                                R = ((((availableLabelPosition - 1) \ 3) + 1) * 2) - 1
                                Select Case availableLabelPosition Mod 3
                                    Case 0
                                        c = 5
                                    Case 2
                                        c = 3
                                    Case 1
                                        c = 1
                                End Select

                                docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c).Range = ""
                            End If
                        Next j
                        
                    Case 30
                        For j = 0 To 29
                            If selectedLabelsBool(j) = False Then
                                availableLabelPosition = GetNumeric(toggleNames(j))
                                        
                                If availableLabelPosition Mod 3 = 0 Then
                                        R = (availableLabelPosition \ 3)
                                    Else
                                        R = (availableLabelPosition \ 3) + 1
                                End If
                                
                                Select Case availableLabelPosition Mod 3
                                    Case 0
                                        c = 5
                                    Case 2
                                        c = 3
                                        docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c + 1).Range = ""
                                    Case 1
                                        c = 1
                                        docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c + 1).Range = ""
                                End Select

                                docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c).Range = ""
                                
                            End If
                        Next j

                    Case 60
                        For j = 0 To 29
                            If selectedLabelsBool(j) = False Then
                                availableLabelPosition = GetNumeric(toggleNames(j))
                                        
                                If availableLabelPosition Mod 3 = 0 Then
                                        R = (availableLabelPosition \ 3)
                                    Else
                                        R = (availableLabelPosition \ 3) + 1
                                End If
                                
                                Select Case availableLabelPosition Mod 3
                                    Case 0
                                        c = 7
                                    Case 2
                                        c = 4
                                    Case 1
                                        c = 1
                                End Select

                                docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c).Range = ""
                                docWord.Tables(1).Cell(R, c + 1).Range = ""
                            End If
                        Next j

                    Case Else
                End Select

            Else
        End If
        
        'Mail merge without involving current project of Access
        'Account for the fact that all the mailmerge entries on the template start with <Next Record> except for the very first entry
        If selectedLabelsBool(0) = True And GetNumeric(toggleNames(0)) = 1 And a = numberOfFullPages + 1 Then
                With docWord.MailMerge
                    .OpenDataSource Name:=tempFile, LinkToSource:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Revert:=True
                    .DataSource.FirstRecord = 2
                    .Execute
                End With
            Else
                With docWord.MailMerge
                    .OpenDataSource Name:=tempFile, LinkToSource:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Revert:=True
                    .DataSource.FirstRecord = 1
                    .Execute
                End With
        End If
        
        docWord.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        
        ''print
        'oApp.ActivePrinter = "HP LaserJet Professional P1102w"
        'oApp.PrintOut Background:=True, Item:=ActiveDocument
        'oApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        
        Kill tempFile
    Next a

    MsgBox "Please review the label word documents that have been generated, make any necessary modifications, and then print.", vbInformation

    'Call CloseWordWindows

'Clean up
    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oSel = Nothing
    

End Function

Public Function GetNumeric(Str As String) As Integer 'extracts the numbers from a string
    Dim StringLength As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    StringLength = Len(Str)
    For i = 1 To StringLength
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Str, i, 1)) Then Result = Result & Mid(Str, i, 1)
    Next i
    GetNumeric = Result
End Function
```

Currently my code runs all the way through (as I am seeing my end MsgBox message), but the Word document never opens. The previous issue was an "object variable or with block not set" which I thought I fixed with the following:

```
Dim oWord           As Object
Dim oWdoc           As Word.Document

'Check if word is open
        Dim docWord As Object
        On Error Resume Next
            Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Word isn't running so start it
                Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        'Open the template
        Let strTemplate = strWordDoc
        Set docWord = oWord.Documents.Add(Template:=strWordDoc, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0, Visible:=True)
```

I can see that it is indeed creating temp files, but the Word document with the correctly formatted labels does not pop up. My template path is not broken or hidden from the program (as it worked before I started getting fancy with formatting).  I am also extremely new to VBA, and am building this off of my predecessor's previous code, so forgive any ignorance on my part.

Comment: Please try `oWord.Visible=True`.

Comment: ... and then you can set breakpoints and start debugging: [Debugging VBA Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20220408130543/http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: I avoid inter-app automation if possible. I would keep this entirely within Access by using a report and temp table.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wrote some code. Took about 20 minutes and 7 lines of VBA to replace all that Word merge mush. Are you interested?

Comment: @June7 would that still allow for label printing on specific label paper and allow techs to alter labels as needed? (mainly font size). If so I'd love to see it; I'm brand new to VBA and am currently just working on updating the code we already have, but am welcome to learning new tricks.

Comment: @taller that did help the issue I was having, and now onto debugging!

Comment: User editing Access report would not be as simple as editing a Word document but should be manageable. User would not edit report directly but select options on a form and then code would set report properties accordingly. For some settings, report would have to be opened in design view, modified, then saved. Explore building a label report in Access - there is a wizard for that (although I seldom use build wizards). It's just a report set to print records in a multi-column format.